# Build Runner not running in project folder

Tags: flutter

I am a newbie in flutter and trying to implement the demo from the "The Boring Show" of Flutter , but right now I am stuck to this issue where I am getting no idea how to get out.
When I am trying to run build runner from the terminal and from the my main project folder , it is not accepting my command. Here is the screenshot I am providing. Can someone please tell me what could be the issue.
Thanks in advance.

[image: Issue of flutter]

EDIT 1:

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
    name: my_app
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:

  url_launcher: any
  built_collection: '>=2.0.0 <5.0.0'
  built_value: '>=5.5.5 <7.0.0'

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:

  build_runner: ^1.0.0
  built_value_generator: ^6.3.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Even on Packages getting, I am not getting any kind of error.

Comment: There might be a problem in your pubspec.yaml file. Please post it's content. Please prefer to post code, log output, and errors as text instead as screenshot.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Here I have updated my pubspec.yaml. Also I am not getting anything in log flutter is unable to run it by not recognising the command in terminal.

Comment: Is the first line of `pubspec.yaml` indented like shown in the question?

Comment: Follow the [Flutter on Windows](https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/install/windows) instructions and make sure that the Path is set correctly.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes this is my actual same copy of pubspec.yaml

Comment: @RichardHeap I have followed each and every item from this page. You can see in the screenshot that flutter doctor is not showing any error.

Comment: You are running `flutter doctor` from `src\flutter\bin` - so naturally it works there. You need to be able to run `flutter doctor` from any arbitrary folder. To achieve that you need to update the path. (You may need to restart `cmd` and/or android studio to get it to pick up the path changes.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    name: my_app
description: A new Flutter application.
...
```

needs to be changed to

```
name: my_app
description: A new Flutter application.
```

Indentation in YAML files is significant.

Comment: I am sorry.. in my last comment I was referring to the content of the file..  the pubspec.yaml is same as you have suggested with proper Indentation.

Comment: My main concern is that why I am showing this message as flutter command is not recognisable in my main project folder.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. I have seen this error multiple times but usually didn't get enough feedback to track down the cause. The best feedback so far was that some errors in `pubspec.yaml` lead to this message. This is what I try to clarify first.